# Using HtmlAgilityPack NuGet package in dotnet core v1.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, html-agility-pack

I am trying to use HtmlAgilityPack nuget package in netcoreapp1.0 (I am restricted to this version since AWS Lambda supports only it). Which version of the HtmlAgilityPack package should I use? The point is .NETStandardLibrary 1.6.0 is only compatible with netcoreapp1.0 but I don't see any version of HtmlAgilityPack which would be compatible with .NETStandardLibrary 1.6.0. The minimum version I can see is .NETStandardLibrary 1.6.1 but this is for netcoreapp1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From a .NET Standard API prospective nothing changed between NETStandard.Library 1.6.1 and 1.6.0. We only bumped the version of the meta-package so that we could pull in newer versions of the dependent packages which contain implementation fixes but no real new API surface for NS1.6.

See the issue #171 in DotNet standard repo [What's the change in NetStandard.Library 1.6.1 vs 1.6.0?](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/171#issuecomment-275773969)

Even if there will be no HtmlAgilityPack compatible (or build against) netstandard1.6, but there is a netstandard1.6.1 I would just build it for myself by replacing netstandard v1.6.1 nuget package with netstandard v1.6 package ( HtmlAgilityPack is open source - right :) ).

Most importantly **there is no netstandard1.6.1**, it was never released or even worked on, **v1.6.1 stands only for the version of NETStandard.Library NuGet package**.